# Shared test resources across modules

Tags: java, maven, testing, module, dependencies

In my project I currently have the following structure:

```
Project:
 |->module1
 |->module2
 |->module3
 \->src
```

The project code (i.e. the code in `src` folder) depends on all 3 modules. Both `module2` and `module3` depend on `module1` (`module1` is basically a bunch of sanity check code utilized wherever needed) and `module3` depends on `module2`.

There are some test resource files that are needed for both `module2`'s and `module3`'s testing as well as for the tests in project's `src`.

My `module2` is basically a utility that parses an input `json` file and translates them in to UDF classes and `module3` takes those objects and handles the processing on them.

I haven't found a solution online for a structure like mine.

P.S. I am also open to suggestions about my overall project structure, if that will simplify things.

Comment: If you really need a resource over module boundaries that is usually an indicator that you are not writing unit tests more integration tests if so then the suggestion to make a separate module which contains those resources is the correct way to go....  apart from that I'm not sure why you have created a `src` directory on the root level where I'm also missing a `pom.xml`...

Comment: `I haven't found a solution online for a structure like mine.` That should give you a good indication you have an issue.  Your structure is what we like to call First Project with Modules(tm). We have all been there.  If this is a career path or you are serious about coding, you are going to want to buckle down and do unit testing. Everything in each module needs to stand on its own, no cross-over.  You can do it, it's tough, but each project the separation gets easier.  Rip it out, do it right.

Comment: Thanks for both of your comments. @khmarbaise, I think you are right, my unit tests are utilising the json parser to parse a sample json so I can use it's output in the module I am trying to test, this makes it more of an integration test. I should rather mock those classes and eliminate my cross module test dependency. Also, I have a pom.xml there I just didn't show it in the question.

Comment: @jnovack, you are right, there should be no dependency, I think I might have felt lazy mocking those objects and instead went for what I did which isn't proper, I should mock those objects not construct them using another module and it's test file.

Answer (score 0):

Introduce a new module called something like test-resources which packages the resources into a normal JAR.

Have all your "real" modules depend on it, making sure to use `test` scope

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>foobar-test-resources</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```